# iphone shares my email address without permission

Tags: contacts, iphone, privacy

I've found that with my iPhone 5 the following happens. When i give out my phone number to other people who also have an iPhone they can see my email address. I would rather this didn't happen. How do I stop it?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean that this happens when using iMessage? (SMS messages sent with a blue background instead of green.) Check your sender ID under Settings: Messages: Sender ID. Change it from your email address to your phone number, or turn off the iMessage service completely.